check acl for restful api when and api used in many pages
I have an api to get list of branches. I have two pages, first page use this api to list branches. Second page is for editing CashDesk record. Each CashDesk related to a branch and in page 2 I need list branches in a select input.
Now I have to use above api for each pages?
Ps. User A could has access to page 2 but has not access to page 1.

Is it OK to have multiple endpoints to get similar data? For example endpoint A to get list of all branches and endpoint B to get only title of branches?
